# appendChild to list element is only affecting the last element of list.

Tags: javascript, html, web, local-storage

I have several element in local storage that I would like to display on screen, I'm achieving this by iterating through the list and using javascript to create the elements and then append them, this is working fine except the button that i am adding is only being added to the final element.  I can't seem to figure out why.  I can append additional text to the same li element but not the button.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
document.getElementById('savedScenarios').appendChild(listSavedScenarios());
        function listSavedScenarios() {
            // Create the list element:
            var listElement = document.createElement('ul');
            var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            button.setAttribute("id", "load");
            var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
            button.appendChild(t);
            for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                // Create the list item:
                var listItem = document.createElement('li');
                //Get the local storage name and add it to the list elmt
                listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(localStorage.key(i)));
                listItem.appendChild(button);
                //update list
                listElement.appendChild(listItem);
            }
            return listElement;
        }
```

the result from the above is:

li - key from storage(1)
 li - key from storage(2)
 li - key from storage(3) click me

Answer (score 3):

> except the button that i am adding is only being added to the final element.

No, it *is* added to each element within your loop – and while that happens, it is of course taken from wherever it might be at that point, because that *is how `appendChild` works* – it removes an element from its current DOM position, before that element is appended somewhere else.

[Interface Node, Method appendchild](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html):

*“Adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this node. If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed.”*

You either have to create a new button to append to the current LI *within* your loop – or at least *clone* the element and append the clone to the current LI.

(And you will have to give the button a different id each time, because an id has to be unique within a document.)

Comment: :) I was just reading that here : http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/appendChild :)
Though, I was creating the butting within the loop and same issue though I wasn't changing the ID